# Fuel Consumption and mileage from OBD2 port parameters.

Tags: automation, obd-ii

I am computing my fuel consumption from OBD2 parameter. MAF to be specific and I am receiving data on per second basis. Here is an section of my data.

```
      TS    RS  EngS    MAF R   MAP    EL   TD Travel

14:41:22    31  932     1056    98  23978   12130
14:41:23    29  2084    2639    107 23210   12130
14:41:24    32  2154    3867    149 38826   12130
14:41:25    36  2426    4683    184 36266   12130
14:41:26    39  2391    3031    133   682   12130
14:41:27    40  1784    2794    132 30634   12130
14:41:28    42  1864    2853    140 30378   12130
14:41:29    43  1953    2900    132 29098   12130
14:41:30    46  2031    3017    135 29098   12130
14:41:31    45  2027    2969    126 20138   12130
14:41:32    47  2122    4253    174 42154   12130
14:41:33    51  2220    4722    183 20906   12130
```

Where 
TS : Time Stamp,
RS : Road Speed,
EngS : Engine Speed,
MAF R :  Mass Air Flow Rate,
MAP Mass Air Pressure,
EL : Engine Load,
TD Travel : Total Distance Traveled

So basically from this data I am trying to compute my Instantaneous Fuel Consumption and The Mileage in KMPL.
For that, Since The Data is per second i am taking MAF of each row and using this formula,

Fuel Consumption = `MAF/(14.7*710)`,

where 14.7 = ideal air/fuel ratio,
and 710 is density of gasoline in grams/L

So, this should give my consumption. and I am calculating the distance(in KM) from `RS /3600`. And further dividing distance by fuel consumption to get mileage. However the calculation is coming horribly wrong. The mileage of my car is around 14KMPL. Here are my results.

```
      TS    Distance (inKM) Fuel Consum(L)  Mileage(KMPL)
14:41:22    0.0086111111    0.1008355216    0.0853975957
14:41:23    0.0080555556    0.2519933158    0.0319673382
14:41:24    0.0088888889    0.369252805     0.0240726374
14:41:25    0.01            0.4471711626    0.0223628016
14:41:26    0.0108333333    0.2894246837    0.0374305785
14:41:27    0.0111111111    0.2667939842    0.0416467828
14:41:28    0.0116666667    0.2724277871    0.0428248043
14:41:29    0.0119444444    0.2769157317    0.0431338602
14:41:30    0.0127777778    0.2880878491    0.0443537546
14:41:31    0.0125          0.2835044163    0.0440910239
14:41:32    0.0130555556    0.4061112437    0.0321477323
14:41:33    0.0141666667    0.4508952017    0.0314189785
```

Can someone tell what am I doing so wrong that the computation is so wrong. As the formulas are simple there isn't much scope to do error.Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAF is in g/s

MAF(g/s) * 1/14.7 * 1L/710g  = Fuel Consumption in L/s Units

Speed (V) is in KPH (Km/hr) so V(Km/hr) * (1hr/3600s) = v KPS(Km/s)

so  FC(L/s) / v (Km/s)  = L/Km

you want Km/L so v/Fc  so your final formula is
KmPL =  V * 1/ 3600 * 1/MAF * 14.7 * 710

Answer (score 0):

Divide the MAF by 14.7 to get Grams of fuel per Sec
next divide by 454 to get lbs fuel/sec
next divide 6.701 to get fuel/sec
multiply by 3600 to get gallons/ hr

other case GPH=MAF*0.0805 next MPG=MPH?GPH